# How to document a self-defined class so that this class can be used with @type in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, netbeans, jsdoc

How to document a self-defined class so that this class can be used with @type in javascript in NetBeans IDE which supports JSDoc in version 2, ScriptDoc and ExtDoc.

So, let me make a example to make a question clear. Basically, I have a class named "Person" which looks like this:

```
/** @namespace */
classes = {
    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {string} name The name of person.'
     */
    Person: function(name) {
        /** @description Name of the person. */
        this.personName = name;
    }
};
```

I have another function will create a person with a name of something.

```
/** @return {classes.Person} something */
var getSomething = function() {
    return new classes.Person("something");
};
```

When I type getSomething(), NetBeans IDE will realize which function I am trying to use. It will also tell me getSomething() will return a object of type classes.Person. However, when I put a dot after it, like

```
getSomething().
```

It do not give me the hint of member personName which means it do not recognize the return type of getSomething is a instance of class classes.Person. However, if I do like this:

```
new classes.Person().
```

It will give me the hint of member personName.

Are there any way to let NetBeans IDE realize it?

Comment: Which NetBeans version do you use? It works for me in older Dev build (from http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/ ). NetBeans 8.1 also supports @typedef that could be used to learn the editor whatever code completion you want, see http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB81#.40typedef

Comment: @ladar I am using Netbeans 8.1. Code completion works perfectly fine when using `@type` within the function. However, it does not work when it is passed by return. Basically, I thought, it works in the function because of variable predict. However, predict seems not work very well when a predicted variable is passed through return value.